# read_excel recode number as na value

Tags: r, import-from-excel, recode, readxl

While importing data from an excel file using the `read_excel` function in the `readxl` package, I have tried specifying a number for the `na` argument but it does not recode the missing values. The data was entered with a numeric value as the missing response.

Example data (in r rather than an excel file though):

```
missing <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                      b = c(99, 2, 3, 4),
                      c = c(1, 99, 3, 4))
```

If the above data were a separate excel file I tried reading it in like so:

```
data <- read_excel("C:/.../missing.xlsx", na = 99)
```

Instead of recoding the 99's to be NA, they just get read in as numbers. I'd like to see a data frame like this without having to use a separate step to recode the data:

```
  a b c
1 1 NA 1
2 2 2 NA
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read_excel is looking for a string. So you just need to type

`data <- read_excel("C:/.../missing.xlsx", na = "99")`

Comment: I tried this with the small example data and it worked, but it isn't working for a dataset with 2000+ rows and 7 columns.

Comment: It actually may have to do with the number I'm trying to replace. The actual data ranges from 1 to 4 with my missing values put in as 5. The `summary` function just says the max is 5.
When I do this to replace 99 it works.

Comment: Actually, one last thought may have done it. Would the 'protected view' cause problems with this? The files were downloaded from the internet and I hadn't opened them in excel. I thought that would only be an excel thing but when I opened the files and saved them it worked.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to turn in to NA in your dataset you can just use `data[data==99]<-NA` or replace the 99 with your number. Or if you are just trying to replace a specific number with NA in a particular column in your dataframe that you've named `data`, like maybe column `b`, you can do `data$b[data$b==99]<-NA`

Comment: If you could accept my response as the answer that would be great!